# Trying to send a double to my DB, "Use of unassigned local variable "lat" + "lng"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to send two doubles as strings to my DB but I get the error: 
"Use of unassigned local variable "lat" + "lng". First time working with doubles so I am not sure what exactly to do.

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder();
Task<IEnumerable<Position>> result =
gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(theEnteredAdress); 
IEnumerable<Position> data = await result;

double lat;
double lng;
foreach (Position p in data)
{   
    lat = p.Latitude;
    lng = p.Longitude;
}

var sendInfo = await dbAPI.createInfo(lat.ToString(), lng.ToString());
// ^^ here are the two errors. I want to send them as strings
```

Comment: Keep in mind also, that you will only have the lat & long of the last position in data. You are overwriting them each time through the foreach loop.

Comment: Are you sure you should be calling out to the API outside of the foreach loop? How many times do you want it to call to the API?

Comment: only one time. it works fine now?

Comment: if i had it inside, i got 2 tables with the same data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this is a little clearer about what is going on and should resolve the problem you are having (which indicates that `GetPositionsForAddressAsync()` is not always returning data):

```
var gc = new Geocoder();
var data = await gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(theEnteredAdress);
var positions = data.ToArray ();
if (positions.Any()) {
    var p = positions.Last ();
    var lat = p.Latitude;
    var lng = p.Longitude;
    var sendInfo = await dbAPI.createInfo(lat.ToString(), lng.ToString());
    // continue....
}
```

Comment: Why put things into Array? Wouldn't 'var p = data.LastOrDefault();' and then checking for null be cleaner?

Comment: @SKall - try it and you will see why. This is an `IEnumerable<Position>`, and `Position` is a struct. Therefore comparing the result of `LastOrDefault()` to `null` is always going to be fruitless. But for reference types, yes I would have done it that way.

Comment: Got it. I would usually use Select in those cases but that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

if `data` had no items, your variables wouldn't be initialized.  Try:

```
double lat = 0;
double lng = 0;
foreach (Position p in data)
{   
    lat = p.Latitude;
    lng = p.Longitude;
}
```

This is strange logic though, you're really just assigning `lat` and `lng` to the last value in `data`

Comment: My guess is that the `await` call was also meant to be done inside the `foreach`.

Comment: so i dont need to foreach out the data? I just want the value of the users entry adress and then send it to the db. it seems to work fine now though?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your variables declaration:

double lat = 0;
double lng = 0;